# Ionic PWA shortcut on desktop

Tags: android, windows, macos, ionic-framework, progressive-web-apps

I'm developing a PWA with Ionic Framework 6.12.2, and I'm wanting to create a shortcut on my computer's desktop (windows and/or mac), I deployed it on firebase, and when I access it on my phone (android) it asks me if I want to create a shortcut and it's like an app even including a splash screen. Is also that possible on windows and mac?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, Luves2spoonge gave me an idea, but it was not the exact solution, so I'm going to answer it.

I don't know why Twitter and other PWAs are having the option to install them directly but mine was requiring first to go to the menu (the three dots in the top right) and then select "more options" > create shortcut > check the option "open as window" and create

[image: https://www.guidingtech.com/install-uninstall-pwas-chrome/]

[image]

this was the blog that helped me: https://www.guidingtech.com/install-uninstall-pwas-chrome/

Answer (score 1):

In Chrome, click the 3 dots in the top right and then you should have an option to install your app. If you don't, you probably have mis-configured your service worker.

Comment: well, I tried it now in chrome and it's not available, I tried with IE and it has installed it!